# One prepaid SIM for 4 weeks of travel in both the US and Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, internet

I'm planning to visit the US and Canada in summer (4 weeks, road trip along the east coast), and I'd like to have mobile internet while being there.

Are there any reasonably priced prepaid SIM options that cover both countries?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything that covers both countries, but I am sure you could get 1 from each country. I haven't switched my phone plan for like 2 years

Answer (score 0):

Straight talk is very reasonable sim only and they cover US and Canada (most US providers cover Canada) http://www.straighttalkbyop.com/

Comment: Hi and welcome. Are you in any way associated with Straight talk?

Comment: Not at all. I work for a software development company. I have colleagues internationally and therefore have second-hand experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Noting wrong with being affiliated with companies, but we do like transparency on TSE. :)